# Error "file in use" when playing aac while appending bytes to aac

Tags: c#, exception, filestream, aac

```
var outputfile = "outputfile.aac";     
var fileList = new List<string>
                {
                    "1.aac",
                    "2.aac",
                    "3.aac",
                    "4.aac",
                    "5.aac",
                    "6.aac"
                };

                foreach (var file in fileList)
                {
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(outputfile, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
                        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                        stream.Flush();
                    }
                }
```

I try to join aac files in fileList into outputfile. when writing file "3.aac" to outputfile.aac, I open outputfile with MediaPlayer, then the FileStream returns exception "file in use", even FileShare mode is ReadWrite, it means that other processes can read and write to the file. So where is the reason?

However, in this case output file is not blocked

```
Stream s = resp.GetResponseStream();
                    var fs = File.Exists(outputFile) ? new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite)
                        : new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    while (s.CanRead)
                    {
                        int bytesRead = s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
```

P/s: I found that the reason because it's aac file

Comment: When you say that `when writing file "3.mp3" to outputfile.mp3, I open outputfile with MediaPlayer` - Do you open the outputfile.mp3 file before executing using statement in Visual Studio or after it?

Comment: Incidentally, no need to do both Flush() and Using in this case.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue. Although I'm using VLC media player to open the file output file. Not sure if it will make any difference since you have used a different music player.

Comment: I open outputfile.mp3 after flush() and before using statement.  the issue occurs on VLC also. Please found the code sample here http://www.mediafire.com/download/7cerhydjseyxdez/Debug.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `FileShare.ReadWrite` you allow subsequent opening of the file in read or write mode.

MediaPlayer then opens the file with `FileShare.Read` on its side, denying you write access to the file.

Comment: Do you know the reason for the second case and how to prevent MediaPlayer from locking write permission?

Comment: @HoàngTrầnHuy You cannot, any decent media player will do the same. You need to rethink why you are trying to do that in the first place.